# Why is the "round figure" of a person associated with being "comforting"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, adjectives, word-usage

**Example:**

> Miss Beam was all that I had expected middle-aged, authoritative, kindly, and understanding. Her hair was beginning to turn grey, and *her round figure* was likely to be comforting for a homesick child to look upon.

Here, I think "her round figure" means the "fullness of her figure". But how exactly would it be comforting? (Especially when in movies, the bad guardians are mostly represented by big, fat people.)

Comment: I dunno, maybe because that was the opinion of the author—or his proxy, the narrator?

Comment: If only the down voters would say why, duh! (I am not new to SE, and have been doing well on other SE sites.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The author is implying that Miss Beam is a *motherly* figure. The classic [Earth Mother](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_goddess) types are often depicted as plump, wide-hipped and full-breasted. The kindly and understanding bit in the previous sentence (of the OP's excerpt) further reinforces this attribute.